# Is Google Appengine right for me

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to create a webapp that is a combination of CMS and CRM with JasperReports capabilities.

The app is to allow groups to present a web presence on the front end and maintain a list of group members on the back end.  I want to build on an opensource CMS and add features I need for my specific purposes. I need to use JasperRepots for pixel perfect printing of distributed materials.

The main thing I need the app to do is support many domains and subdomains allowing me the ability to add new features and bug fixes across all instances.

After reading a few post I'll answer some questions.  By many domains I mean less than 100 the first few years and up from there at about 20 per year.  Image storage would be minimal.  All the sites would look basically the same and use 1 set of images.  Each domain or subdomain would have less that 5GB image storage.

Thanks for your help and any suggestions.

Comment: to add on rafanunes answer, I think AmazonWs is more suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.
For PDF export Jasper uses iText that is not supported on GAE.
And for 'pixel perfect' Jasper uses java.awt classes, that most of them are not supported also.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine-java/oH0jGwCGrV8

Comment: rafanunes, Thanks that is the kind of info I was looking for.